# Setting Oracle Timestamp with Coldfusion

Tags: oracle, coldfusion

This is a pretty simple question, and I searched the previous questions but couldn't find an answer.

How do you insert or create a timestamp in Oracle using Coldfusion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can insert it like this:

```
<cfquery name="qTest">
  insert into myTable(myTimestampCol)
  values (<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_timestamp" value="#now()#" />)
</cfquery>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: You can also use Oracle's SYSDATE.

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks!    <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_timestamp" value="#now()#" /> worked swimmingly!

Comment: Actually, this seems to cause cursor problems.  Does anyone know about this?

Comment: Perhaps post that as a different question?

Comment: Ok, I will, thank  you. -- After I diligently research to see if it exists on the site. :)

Answer (score 2):

Use Oracle's built-in SYSDATE function.

```
<cfquery name="qTest">
  insert into myTable(myTimestampCol)
  values (SYSDATE)
</cfquery>
```

When possible, I prefer the built-in database function for stuff like this. It's based on the database server clock rather than the ColdFusion server clock. It also avoids the ever-so-small overhead of converting a string to a date and putting it in a bind variable.